# Python 3.2.1: Variable Referenced Before Assignment, Previously Working

Tags: python, graphics, return

I have searched through similar questions on here, and cannot find an exact answer. I keep getting a "...referenced before assignment" error.

I am trying to put two graphics objects returned from one function into two variables in another function.

I had basically the exact same piece of code in an earlier version, and it worked just fine.

I have the piece of code:

```
if moveE:
    moved_ctr, nT = MoveCharacter(ctr, spaceSize, borderSet, "east")
if moveW:
    moved_ctr, nT = MoveCharacter(ctr, spaceSize, borderSet, "west")
moved_ctr.draw(board)
```

This is what MoveCharacter() looks like:

```
def MoveCharacter(character, spSz, bdSet, direction):
    x1 = character.getCenter().getX()
    x2 = bdSet
    y1 = character.getCenter().getY()
    y2 = bdSet
    notifyText = Text(Point(100, 100), "")

    character.undraw()

    distance = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)

    if direction == "east":
            if distance < spSz:
                    character.move(spSz, 0)
            else:
                    notifyText.setText("You cannot move right from where you currently are.")
    if direction == "west":
            if distance > spSz:
                    character.move(-1 * spSz, 0)
            else:
                    notifyText.setText("You cannot move left from where you currently are.")

    return character, notifyText
```

And I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    Grid()
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 70, in Grid
    moved_ctr.draw(board)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'moved_ctr' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: `in an earlier version` of what ? (_In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens before `if moveE:`?

Most likely, `moveE` and `moveW` are falsey.

Comment: This: 
`moveE = rectIntersect(gE, click)
 moveW = rectIntersect(gW, click)`
is what's before `if moveE:`. Again, that code remained unchanged from before, and it returned `True` when I clicked on the respective buttons. The `rectIntersect()` is just an instructor-provided function to check if a mouse click is within a given rectangle. Although now that I test what those values are when I do click those respective buttons, that may be where part of the problem lies.

Comment: It might be worth printing out both `moveE` and `moveW`, for debugging purposes. It seems like your problem is that both are `False` and so `maved_ctr` isn't getting assigned to.

Comment: @Dougal: When I print `moveE` and `moveW`, they do say `False`, regardless of whether I click on either one of them. I am trying to figure out why it's not working now, though, because earlier, I got one to return `True` and the other `False`, meaning it was getting it all correct and it would take the appropriate action depending on which was clicked.

Comment: When you "click on" what? Ask a new question about the specific graphics API you're using and the values you're getting from the UI.